# Default and 1 additional Tailwind theme

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

I have been asked to add 1 new theme to an existing project that currently uses Tailwind.

The new theme should only take affect when 'theme-name' exists in the body tag class attribute.

The existing tailwind.config.js is like this:

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');

var colors = {
  gray: {
    DEFAULT: '#868692',
    50: '#F9FAFB',
    100: '#F5F5FA',
    200: '#E9E9EE',
    300: '#D1D5DB',
    400: '#9CA3AF',
    500: '#868692',
    600: '#667085',
    700: '#504F4F',
    800: '#2D3047',
    900: '#111827'
  },
  primary: {
    DEFAULT: '#009BF5',
    50: '#DBF2FF',
    100: '#E5F6FE',
    200: '#8FD6FF',
    300: '#5CC3FF',
    400: '#29B0FF',
    500: '#009BF5',
    600: '#0078BD',
    700: '#005485',
    800: '#00314D',
    900: '#000D15',
    contrast: '#FFFFFF'
  },
  secondary: {
    DEFAULT: '#744FC6',
    50: '#EFEBF9',
    100: '#E2DAF3',
    200: '#C6B7E8',
    300: '#AB94DC',
    400: '#8F72D1',
    500: '#744FC6',
    600: '#5936A7',
    700: '#42287C',
    800: '#2C1B52',
    900: '#150D28',
    contrast: '#FFFFFF'
  },
  success: {
    DEFAULT: '#14CC76',
    50: '#B7F8D9',
    100: '#A2F6CF',
    200: '#78F2B9',
    300: '#4EEEA3',
    400: '#24EA8D',
    500: '#14CC76',
    600: '#10A761',
    700: '#0D824B',
    800: '#095D36',
    900: '#053720',
    contrast: '#FFFFFF'
  },
  error: {
    DEFAULT: '#FC446F',
    50: '#FFF9FA',
    100: '#FFE5EB',
    200: '#FEBCCC',
    300: '#FD94AD',
    400: '#FD6C8E',
    500: '#FC446F',
    600: '#FB0D44',
    700: '#CD0332',
    800: '#950225',
    900: '#5E0217',
    contrast: '#FFFFFF'
  },
  warning: {
    DEFAULT: '#FD8204',
    50: '#FEDDBA',
    100: '#FEF8EF',
    200: '#FEBE7D',
    300: '#FEAA55',
    400: '#FD962C',
    500: '#FD8204',
    600: '#D66D02',
    700: '#AE5901',
    800: '#864401',
    900: '#5D2F01',
    contrast: '#FFFFFF'
  }
};
colors.ui = {
  text: colors.gray['800'],
  textDim: colors.gray['500'],
  border: colors.gray['200'],
  borderDim: colors.gray['100'],
  borderDark: colors.gray['500'],
  bg: '#FFFFFF',
  bgDim: colors.gray['100'],
  bgDimmer: colors.gray['50']
};

/** @type {import("tailwindcss").Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false // To replace with another that solves some issues with tailwind preflight classes
  },
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: colors,
      textColor: {
        default: colors.ui.text,
        dim: colors.ui.textDim
      },
      backgroundColor: {
        default: colors.ui.bg,
        dim: colors.ui.bgDim,
        dimmer: colors.ui.bgDimmer
      },
      borderColor: {
        default: colors.ui.border,
        dim: colors.ui.borderDim,
        dark: colors.ui.borderDark
      },
      borderRadius: {
        card: '0.625rem'
      },
      boxShadow: {
        lg: '0 0 16px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02)'
      },
      fontSize: {
        '2xs': '0.625rem',
        '3.5xl': '2rem'
      },
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Poppins', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
        // TODO: Install Gibson font
        mono: [
          'canada-type-gibson, sans-serif',
          ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.mono
        ]
        // serif: ['icomoon, sans-serif', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.serif]
      },
      zIndex: {
        dropdown: 1000,
        modal: 9000
      },
      transitionProperty: {
        position: 'width,height,left,top'
      },
      transitionTimingFunction: {
        'out-back': 'cubic-bezier(0.34, 1.56, 0.64, 1)'
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/forms'), require('@tailwindcss/typography')]
};
```

...only the colours are changing in this new additional theme.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction to set this up? I already have the 'theme-name' in my body tag class attribute.

Thanks for any guidance,
K...

Comment: You could consider using `[.theme-name_&]:` [arbitrary variant](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#using-arbitrary-variants) to apply different colors where needed, i.e. `bg-black [.theme-name_&]:bg-white`. You could also refactor [the variant into a Tailwind plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#static-variants).

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found tailwindcss-themer and this did the trick.

https://github.com/RyanClementsHax/tailwindcss-themer

const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');

```
var colors = {
  gray: {
    DEFAULT: '#868692',
    50: '#F9FAFB',
    100: '#F5F5FA',
    200: '#E9E9EE',
    300: '#D1D5DB',
    400: '#9CA3AF',
    500: '#868692',
    600: '#667085',
    700: '#504F4F',
    800: '#2D3047',
    900: '#111827'
  },
  primary: {
    DEFAULT: '#009BF5',
    50: '#DBF2FF',
    100: '#E5F6FE',
    200: '#8FD6FF',
    300: '#5CC3FF',
    400: '#29B0FF',
    500: '#009BF5',
    600: '#0078BD',
    700: '#005485',
    800: '#00314D',
    900: '#000D15',
    contrast: '#FFFFFF'
  },
  secondary: {
    DEFAULT: '#744FC6',
    50: '#EFEBF9',
    100: '#E2DAF3',
    200: '#C6B7E8',
    300: '#AB94DC',
    400: '#8F72D1',
    500: '#744FC6',
    600: '#5936A7',
    700: '#42287C',
    800: '#2C1B52',
    900: '#150D28',
    contrast: '#FFFFFF'
  },
  success: {
    DEFAULT: '#14CC76',
    50: '#B7F8D9',
    100: '#A2F6CF',
    200: '#78F2B9',
    300: '#4EEEA3',
    400: '#24EA8D',
    500: '#14CC76',
    600: '#10A761',
    700: '#0D824B',
    800: '#095D36',
    900: '#053720',
    contrast: '#FFFFFF'
  },
  error: {
    DEFAULT: '#FC446F',
    50: '#FFF9FA',
    100: '#FFE5EB',
    200: '#FEBCCC',
    300: '#FD94AD',
    400: '#FD6C8E',
    500: '#FC446F',
    600: '#FB0D44',
    700: '#CD0332',
    800: '#950225',
    900: '#5E0217',
    contrast: '#FFFFFF'
  },
  warning: {
    DEFAULT: '#FD8204',
    50: '#FEDDBA',
    100: '#FEF8EF',
    200: '#FEBE7D',
    300: '#FEAA55',
    400: '#FD962C',
    500: '#FD8204',
    600: '#D66D02',
    700: '#AE5901',
    800: '#864401',
    900: '#5D2F01',
    contrast: '#FFFFFF'
  },
  info: { // used for alarts and status
    DEFAULT: '#009BF5',
    50: '#DBF2FF',
    100: '#E5F6FE',
    200: '#8FD6FF',
    300: '#5CC3FF',
    400: '#29B0FF',
    500: '#009BF5',
    600: '#0078BD',
    700: '#005485',
    800: '#00314D',
    900: '#000D15',
    contrast: '#FFFFFF'
  },
};
colors.ui = {
  text: colors.gray['800'],
  textDim: colors.gray['500'],
  border: colors.gray['200'],
  borderDim: colors.gray['100'],
  borderDark: colors.gray['500'],
  bg: '#FFFFFF',
  bgDim: colors.gray['100'],
  bgDimmer: colors.gray['50']
};

var colorsSB = {
  gray: {
    DEFAULT: '#868692',
    50: '#F9FAFB',
    100: '#F5F5FA',
    200: '#E9E9EE',
    300: '#D1D5DB',
    400: '#9CA3AF',
    500: '#868692',
    600: '#667085',
    700: '#504F4F',
    800: '#2D3047',
    900: '#111827'
  },
  primary: {
    DEFAULT: '#F7941D',
    50: '#FDEBDB',
    100: '#FCE3CC',
    200: '#F9C298',
    300: '#F7AD64',
    400: '#F69430',
    500: '#F7941D',
    600: '#F67900',
    700: '#E06200',
    800: '#C74A00',
    900: '#A83100',
    contrast: '#FFFFFF'
  },
  secondary: {
    DEFAULT: '#744FC6',
    50: '#EFEBF9',
    100: '#E2DAF3',
    200: '#C6B7E8',
    300: '#AB94DC',
    400: '#8F72D1',
    500: '#744FC6',
    600: '#5936A7',
    700: '#42287C',
    800: '#2C1B52',
    900: '#150D28',
    contrast: '#FFFFFF'
  },
  success: {
    DEFAULT: '#14CC76',
    50: '#B7F8D9',
    100: '#A2F6CF',
    200: '#78F2B9',
    300: '#4EEEA3',
    400: '#24EA8D',
    500: '#14CC76',
    600: '#10A761',
    700: '#0D824B',
    800: '#095D36',
    900: '#053720',
    contrast: '#FFFFFF'
  },
  error: {
    DEFAULT: '#FC446F',
    50: '#FFF9FA',
    100: '#FFE5EB',
    200: '#FEBCCC',
    300: '#FD94AD',
    400: '#FD6C8E',
    500: '#FC446F',
    600: '#FB0D44',
    700: '#CD0332',
    800: '#950225',
    900: '#5E0217',
    contrast: '#FFFFFF'
  },
  warning: {
    DEFAULT: '#FD8204',
    50: '#FEDDBA',
    100: '#FEF8EF',
    200: '#FEBE7D',
    300: '#FEAA55',
    400: '#FD962C',
    500: '#FD8204',
    600: '#D66D02',
    700: '#AE5901',
    800: '#864401',
    900: '#5D2F01',
    contrast: '#FFFFFF'
  },
  info: { // used for alarts and status
    DEFAULT: '#009BF5',
    50: '#DBF2FF',
    100: '#E5F6FE',
    200: '#8FD6FF',
    300: '#5CC3FF',
    400: '#29B0FF',
    500: '#009BF5',
    600: '#0078BD',
    700: '#005485',
    800: '#00314D',
    900: '#000D15',
    contrast: '#FFFFFF'
  },
};
colorsSB.ui = {
  text: colorsSB.gray['800'],
  textDim: colorsSB.gray['500'],
  border: colorsSB.gray['200'],
  borderDim: colorsSB.gray['100'],
  borderDark: colorsSB.gray['500'],
  bg: '#FFFFFF',
  bgDim: colorsSB.gray['100'],
  bgDimmer: colorsSB.gray['50']
};

/** @type {import("tailwindcss").Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false // To replace with another that solves some issues with tailwind preflight classes
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
    require('tailwindcss-themer')({
      defaultTheme: {
        // put the default values of any config you want themed
        // just as if you were to extend tailwind's theme like normal https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme#extending-the-default-theme
        extend: {
          colors: colors,
          textColor: {
            default: colors.ui.text,
            dim: colors.ui.textDim
          },
          backgroundColor: {
            default: colors.ui.bg,
            dim: colors.ui.bgDim,
            dimmer: colors.ui.bgDimmer
          },
          borderColor: {
            default: colors.ui.border,
            dim: colors.ui.borderDim,
            dark: colors.ui.borderDark
          },
          borderRadius: {
            card: '0.625rem'
          },
          boxShadow: {
            lg: '0 0 16px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02)'
          },
          fontSize: {
            '2xs': '0.625rem',
            '3.5xl': '2rem'
          },
          fontFamily: {
            sans: ['Poppins', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
            // TODO: Install Gibson font
            mono: [
              'canada-type-gibson, sans-serif',
              ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.mono
            ]
            // serif: ['icomoon, sans-serif', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.serif]
          },
          zIndex: {
            dropdown: 1000,
            modal: 9000
          },
          transitionProperty: {
            position: 'width,height,left,top'
          },
          transitionTimingFunction: {
            'out-back': 'cubic-bezier(0.34, 1.56, 0.64, 1)'
          }
        }
      },
      themes: [
        {
          // name your theme anything that could be a valid css class name
          // remember what you named your theme because you will use it as a class to enable the theme
          name: 'additionalThemeName',
          // put any overrides your theme has here
          // just as if you were to extend tailwind's theme like normal https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme#extending-the-default-theme
          extend: {
            colors: colorsSB,
            textColor: {
              default: colorsSB.ui.text,
              dim: colorsSB.ui.textDim
            },
            backgroundColor: {
              default: colorsSB.ui.bg,
              dim: colorsSB.ui.bgDim,
              dimmer: colorsSB.ui.bgDimmer
            },
            borderColor: {
              default: colorsSB.ui.border,
              dim: colorsSB.ui.borderDim,
              dark: colorsSB.ui.borderDark
            },
            borderRadius: {
              card: '0.625rem'
            },
            boxShadow: {
              lg: '0 0 16px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02)'
            },
            fontSize: {
              '2xs': '0.625rem',
              '3.5xl': '2rem'
            },
            fontFamily: {
              sans: ['Poppins', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
              // TODO: Install Gibson font
              mono: [
                'canada-type-gibson, sans-serif',
                ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.mono
              ]
              // serif: ['icomoon, sans-serif', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.serif]
            },
            zIndex: {
              dropdown: 1000,
              modal: 9000
            },
            transitionProperty: {
              position: 'width,height,left,top'
            },
            transitionTimingFunction: {
              'out-back': 'cubic-bezier(0.34, 1.56, 0.64, 1)'
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: or you might just try [tw-colors](https://github.com/L-Blondy/tw-colors), it is way easier and cleaner